# Hosting an express app on Heroku error with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, ionic2

I'm building a mean stack app with ionic 2 and I want to host it on Heroku. The app is finished and runs fine locally and I have it connected to a mLabs database. When I push the app to Heroku I am getting the following error in the logs.

```
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558949+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558952+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558952+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:4:16)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.558950+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-04-10T12:32:15.567486+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.577504+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-04-10T12:32:15.577867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-04-10T12:32:15.578113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2017-04-10T12:32:15.578341+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-04-10T12:32:15.578578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-04-10T12:32:15.578785+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ start: `node server.js`
2017-04-10T12:32:15.578954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-04-10T12:32:15.579249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-04-10T12:32:15.579426+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ start script 'node server.js'.
2017-04-10T12:32:15.579621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-04-10T12:32:15.579920+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-04-10T12:32:15.579746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580101+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580265+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580878+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
2017-04-10T12:32:15.580993+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-04-10T12:32:15.588769+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.589345+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-04-10T12:32:15.589646+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-04-10T12:32:15.679397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-10T12:32:15.680194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-10T12:32:15.673049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-04-10T12:32:18.568796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-04-10T12:32:21.743026+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:21.743041+00:00 app[web.1]: > ionic-hello-world@ start /app
2017-04-10T12:32:21.743042+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-04-10T12:32:21.743042+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058223+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058237+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058236+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058239+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058238+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058241+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058242+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058242+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:4:16)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058244+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058245+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058245+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.058246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-04-10T12:32:22.067921+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.080492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-04-10T12:32:22.080827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-04-10T12:32:22.080991+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081825+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081993+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ start script 'node server.js'.
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-04-10T12:32:22.081490+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ start: `node server.js`
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082498+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082666+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-04-10T12:32:22.082832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.083001+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
2017-04-10T12:32:22.083168+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.083170+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
2017-04-10T12:32:22.083338+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-04-10T12:32:22.092234+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.092236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-04-10T12:32:22.092237+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-04-10T12:32:22.188511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-04-10T12:32:22.201942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-10T12:32:50.415338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dry-retreat-69141.herokuapp.com request_id=898a0974-f3eb-47b2-a7ca-77a37cf99131 fwd="193.1.57.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-04-10T12:35:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alanmurphy1995@gmail.com
2017-04-10T12:36:27.620672+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user alanmurphy1995@gmail.com
2017-04-10T12:36:27.620672+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9f02cb4 by user alanmurphy1995@gmail.com
2017-04-10T12:36:27.804049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-10T12:36:27.782474+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user alanmurphy1995@gmail.com
2017-04-10T12:35:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-04-10T12:36:33.381932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-04-10T12:36:36.544686+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:36:36.544709+00:00 app[web.1]: > ionic-hello-world@ start /app
2017-04-10T12:36:36.544710+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-04-10T12:36:36.544711+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T12:36:37.082619+00:00 app[web.1]: App listening on port 8080
2017-04-10T12:37:33.784488+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2017-04-10T12:37:33.760270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-04-10T12:37:33.760270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-04-10T12:37:33.878656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2017-04-10T12:37:33.889982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-10T12:37:34.773926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dry-retreat-69141.herokuapp.com request_id=6ba08c4e-a269-4530-b0db-192da56e2724 fwd="193.1.57.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

For reference this is my server.js file

```
// Set up
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var cors = require('cors');

// Configuration
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/reviewking');
mongoose.connect('Connecting to mLabs here URI not included for security reasons');

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("www")); // Our Ionic app build is in the www folder (kept up-to-date by the Ionic CLI using 'ionic serve')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});

// Models
var Review = mongoose.model('Review', {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    rating: Number
});

// Routes

    // Get reviews
    app.get('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {

        console.log("fetching reviews");

        // use mongoose to get all reviews in the database
        Review.find(function(err, reviews) {

            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (err)
                res.send(err)

            res.json(reviews); // return all reviews in JSON format
        });
    });

    // create review and send back all reviews after creation
    app.post('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {

        console.log("creating review");

        // create a review, information comes from request from Ionic
        Review.create({
            title : req.body.title,
            description : req.body.description,
            rating: req.body.rating,
            done : false
        }, function(err, review) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // get and return all the reviews after you create another
            Review.find(function(err, reviews) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(reviews);
            });
        });

    });

    // delete a review
    app.delete('/api/reviews/:review_id', function(req, res) {
        Review.remove({
            _id : req.params.review_id
        }, function(err, review) {

        });
    });


// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

And this is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-network-information": "0.0.3",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "firebase": "^3.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.1.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.9",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.0",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "superlogin": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.9",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.0",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "superlogin": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "ReviewApp: An Ionic project"
}
```

Any help with this error or a solution around this so I can push a working app to Heroku would help greatly.

Comment: Are you sure the `mongoose` module is installed? (beside being listed in the `package.json` file, it should also be present in the node_modules folder.
Try to run `npm install` to install all your packages again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `mongoose` from `devDependencies` should fix it.

Explanation: mongoose is listed twice in `package.json` - once in `dependencies` and once in `devDependencies`, which don't get installed by Heroku.

I also suggest you alphabetize those dependency lists so that this kind of issue is easier to catch in the future.